# Is it okay to define the actual argument as `const int` but declare it as just `int` in the header?

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, constants

See the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a);

int main()
{
  f(10);
  return 0;
}

void f(const int a)
{
  /* a = 20; */ /* Want to avoid accidental modification of a. */
  printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

In this program the declaration of the function `f()` does not exactly match the definition. The declaration has `int a` as the parameter but the definition has `const int a` as the parameter.

Here are my questions about this program.

1. I believe this is okay because, the code that calls `f()` doesn't have to know whether the actual argument `a` is treated as constant within `f()`. That bit of detail is private to `f()`. That's none of the calling code's concern. As far as the caller is concerned, nothing about `int a` that is visible to it can change while calling `f()` in either case. Am I right?
2. Is it common to declare the actual arguments in the function definitions as `const int` or `const char *const` but declare them in the header as just `int` or `const char *`? If not, do you recommend this way? To keep this second question objective, please list the pros and cons of doing this.

Comment: No, it's not really ok. this should give a warning, because the implementation is different from the declaration.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Neither Clang nor GCC give a warning about this, even at `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz As far as I understand, `f(const int a)` and `f(int a)` mean the same thing to the caller, i.e. in either case `f()` cannot alter anything about `a` that the caller can see. Also, I compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 foo.c`. There were no warnings.

Comment: Does your compiler not show you warnings?

Comment: @AnishSharma I am not sure what you mean. Did you read the comments above?

Comment: @MichaelWalz this code is correct

Answer (score 8):

Some software houses insist on marking function parameters `const` if possible as there is a school of thought that suggests your function is more stable (and less vulnerable to errant refactoring) if you do that since you can't unintentionally modify an input parameter.

The C standard allows you to use non-`const` parameters in a function declaration, and `const` in the definition.

Personally I don't do it as I like my prototypes to match my definitions. I'd imagine that you could confuse code analysis packages too.

Comment: Can you point to the section in the C standard that allows non-`const` parameter in declaration and `const` in definition? The other answer by Grzegorz Szpetkowski seems to contradict this claim. It would be nice if we can prove this claim with references to the C standard.

Comment: @LoneLearner: I deleted my answer, since it was wrong on that aspect. More specifically, I missed the 6.7.6.3/15, which essentially tells that `const` qualifier is dropped for resolving compatibility.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski You should probably undelete your answer and update it to make it correct. Your answer had really useful references to the C standard that would help answer this question with sufficient proof.

Comment: @Bathsheba Since you mention that you like your prototypes to match your definitions, which one of the two possible styles do you use? (1) Do you use `const int a` in both the definition and declaration? (2) Or do you use just `int a` in both the definition and declaration?

Comment: @LoneLearner the references in the deleted answer are not relevant , just the one in T.C.'s comment which is 6.7.6.3/15. "In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type."